# How do services in Debian work, and how can I manage them?

Tags: debian, startup, services, subversion, sysvinit

In Windows I have the services manager, where I see all system services, that can be started through Windows itself, I set up the user it uses, the rights management is in there, and I can pass variables and some other information to the services, I can name them, and I can create duplicates services of one program and so on. So I have a main management tool in Windows.

How can I do the same in Linux? How can I trigger to run "svnserve" at startup, or how can I configure services to be running in a special context. How can I view all "programmed" services?

Comment: What distribution and version are you using? Service management (services are almost always called ‘daemons’ in the Unix world) used to be easy and semi-standard. Things are more varied these days. And not always nice. :)

Also, what do you mean by **context**?

Comment: Though it does seem that systemd is slowly winning the init system war. Debian is the last big holdout still using the old SysVinit, and is currently in the process of determining which init system to go with.

Comment: Currently I work with Debian (latest stable), and by **context** I mean path-variables or a specified user-context.

Comment: If you need only to use `server` command at Debian, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226089/130402

Answer (score 131, accepted):

There are currently 3 main init systems used by linux. A few years ago, there was just one, SysVinit. But SysVinit was seriously lacking in capabilities such as service dependency graphing, so it's been deprecated in most distros by now. Currently most distros are switching to [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). Though there is also [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

But here's the answer to your question for each of the 3 init systems:

### SysVinit

SysVinit currently used by Debian and RedHat. Though the next version of RedHat (7) will be using systemd.

The univeral way of enabling SysVinit services on boot is to symlink them in `/etc/rc3.d` (or `/etc/rc2.d`). All services can be found in `/etc/init.d`. Note however that distros will often have their own tool for managing these files, and that tool should be used instead. (Fedora/RedHat has `service` and `chkconfig`, ubuntu has `update-rc.d`)

#### List services:

```
ls /etc/init.d/
```

#### Start service:

```
/etc/init.d/{SERVICENAME} start
```

or

```
service {SERVICENAME} start
```

#### Stop service:

```
/etc/init.d/{SERVICENAME} stop
```

or

```
service {SERVICENAME} stop
```

#### Enable service:

```
cd /etc/rc3.d
ln -s ../init.d/{SERVICENAME} S95{SERVICENAME}
```

*(the `S95` is used to specify the order. S01 will start before S02, etc)*

#### Disable service:

```
rm /etc/rc3.d/*{SERVICENAME}
```

### Systemd

The most notable distribution using systemd is Fedora. Though it is used by many others. Additionally, with Debian having chosen to go with systemd over upstart, it will become the defacto upstart system for most distributions (ubuntu has already announced they will be dropping upstart for systemd).

#### List services:

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

#### Start service:

```
systemctl start {SERVICENAME}
```

#### Stop service:

```
systemctl stop {SERVICENAME}
```

#### Enable service:

```
systemctl enable {SERVICENAME}
```

#### Disable service:

```
systemctl disable {SERVICENAME}
```

### Upstart

Upstart was developed by the Ubuntu folks. But after debian [decided to go with systemd](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=727708), Ubuntu [announced they would drop upstart](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316).

Upstart was also briefly used by RedHat, as it is present in RHEL-6, but it is not commonly used.

#### List services:

```
initctl list
```

#### Start service:

```
initctl start {SERVICENAME}
```

#### Stop service:

```
initctl stop {SERVICENAME}
```

#### Enable service:

2 ways unfortunately:

1. There will be a file `/etc/default/{SERVICENAME}` which contains a line `ENABLED=...`. Change this line to `ENABLED=1`.
2. There will be a file `/etc/init/{SERVICENAME}.override`. Make sure it contains `start` (or is absent entirely), not `manual`.

#### Disable service:

```
echo manual > /etc/init/{SERVICENAME}.override
```

---

*Note: There is also the 'OpenRC' init system which is used by Gentoo. Currently Gentoo is the only distro which uses it, and it is not being considered for use, nor supported by any other distro. So I am not covering it's usage (though if opinion is that I do, I can add it).*

Comment: OpenRC is kinda of an abstraction for SysVinit. It doesn't replace it, it adds to it.

Comment: Great writeup! Just a couple minor corrections: RHEL 6.x (and thus, CentOS 6.x and the rest of derivatives) uses upstart, like Ubuntu (though most of the services still use SysV scripts anyway). Also, I'd add that "chkconfig" (RH) and "update-rc.d" (Debian) are the "official" ways to add links to rc?.d directories.

Comment: @rsuarez good point on the RHEL6 thing. Though not much seems to use it. Most of the system still runs via legacy SysVinit (17 upstart, 89 SysVinit on one of my RHEL6 systems). And `chkconfig` and `update-rc.d` are mentioned. See second paragraph under **SysVinit** :-)

Comment: @Patrick agree on #1; "oops!" on #2 :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, now I've got the big-picture. Currently I am using **Debian** (latest stable), here in German-speaking Europe it has the best recommendations, but maybe I'll give Redhat a try.

Comment: Alpine also uses OpenRC.

Answer (score 12):

Different distributions use different mechanisms to manage services. The software to manage services is called [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), after the traditional name for the very first process (with process ID 1) which is in charge of starting the others.

Debian uses the traditional [SysVinit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) variant of init. Under this system, there is a collection of scripts in the directory `/etc/init` (this and other location may vary slightly between distributions that use SysVinit). These scripts are not invoked directly, but through symbolic links in directories `/etc/rc?.d`. It is the presence and the name of these symbolic links that determine when services are started. For more details, read the [chapter on init in the Debian Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_sysv_style_init).

Have a look in `/etc/rc?.d` to see what services are already present. The letter or digit before the dot is the runlevel; entries whose name starts with `S` are executed with the argument `start` when entering the runlevel, and entries whose name starts with `K` are executed when leaving the runlevel. The normal runlevel sequence is: S during boot (so `/etc/rcS.d/S*` are executed), then 2 (so `/etc/rc2.d/S*` are executed). At shutdown time, `/etc/rc2.d/K*` are executed, then the runlevel switches to 0 (or 6 for a reboot).

In a nutshell, if you want to create a startup script for a new service:

- Write a shell script in `/etc/init.d`. This script must accept one argument which may be `start`, `stop`, `force-reload`, `restart`, or (optional) `reload` or `status`. The difference between `reload` and `restart` is that `restart` is equivalent to `stop` followed by `start` while `reload` reloads the configuration without stopping anything (if the service supports it); `force-reload` does `reload` if available and `restart` otherwise. See the existing files and [Making scripts run at boot time with Debian](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28) for examples.
- Run [`update-rc.d`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=update-rc.d) to create symbolic links to start and stop your service. Most services run in runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Note that to provide svn access, it may be easier to set up Apache and use the HTTP or HTTPS protocol. This has the side benefit of allowing quick repository browsing through a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

From A traditional unix background, there is nothing special about services. Services are just process, but with two exceptions: they don't need a terminal and they get started at boot. how they get started at boot depends on init (which could be sysv init, bsd init, upstart, systemd or something else; check your man page for init) and whether your are using a wrapper for the task or for the init configuration. There is nothing stopping you from running a service from a terminal, in fact it is common for testing purposes.