# Server socket location, startup and monitoring

Tags: directory-structure, services

I'm writing a server on a shared development desktop that moonlights as a server.

This is my first attempt at writing a linux server for someone else on a shared box.  I'd like to conform to unix standards and make it as professional as possible.

In what directory should the websocket server be placed?  I was thinking `/var`, but it's `root`'s, so I don't know how exactly to navigate that.

How should execution be managed?  In other words, should a new group be made that has permissions to execute the server in case it crashes or needs restarting?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by “websocket”. If this is a web server, it listens on TCP, and there's no reason why it would also have to listen through a unix socket.

Assuming you do want to use a unix socket, if your server is started by root, you can create a subdirectory in [`/var/run`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARRUNRUNTIMEVARIABLEDATA), give your daemon write permissions there, and have your daemon create its socket there under a predictable name (e.g. `/var/run/gracchusd/sock`). If your server is not started by root, you can create the socket under [`/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES), with a name containing a randomly-generated part (e.g. `/tmp/gracchusd-nyBBCxs9.sock`). Generally speaking, the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) tells you the main rules about where to put files (though beware that it's a little out of date, in particular it [doesn't mention `/run`](https://bugs.linuxfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718) which is now common but not yet universal).

To start and stop your service, create service starting scripts or description files. You (or the people who port your server to different distributions) will need to create one for each [init system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) as they [work differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106656/how-do-services-in-debian-work-and-how-can-i-manage-them/106674#106674). Some init systems come with their own monitoring mechanism, or you can use a separate [monitoring daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/881/ensure-a-process-is-always-running).

Unless your server needs to run as root, it is good practice to run it as a dedicated user and group. Configuration files should be owned by root and not group-writable, so that even if the daemon is breached, the attacker cannot change the configuration. If the daemon needs to read confidential files, they can be owned by root or other users and readable by the daemon group.

Comment: Thank you Giles!  It's websockets and great! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket  It's written with java, so the server merely needs to be started with `java`, but I'm not sure what directory it should be in to conform to unix best practices.  Also, I really have no idea how to set up the user/group structure so that the right users can start it, preferably as an awesome server daemon.  Your answer seems like a great start.  Please let me know if there's anything more specific I can provide to make my situation clearer.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus So you mean websocket as in websocket? In that case, there is no socket file. What file's location are you wondering about?

Comment: Well, apache2 has its files in `/var/www`, and other well written programs are in more "unixy" locations.  The only thing I know to do is just stick it in my `~`, but other users may need to start it, yet I don't want them in my directory, and it's not as classy and well-organized as having it in a more standard directory.  Does any of that make sense?  Thank you so much again in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus You mean data files? That depends on what kind of data this is. User data lives in users' home directories. System data can live under `/var`, or in other directories chosen by the system administrator. The modern location (but not quite a de facto standard) is [`/srv`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM).

Comment: Hmm, I guess after I read your links, I might have a clearer idea of how this should go.  I think I might only halfway know what the problem is and can't properly express myself yet.  Thank you so very much!